Closed-form solution for expectation of logistic function where the underlying random variable is lognormal distribution?
I would like to find the expectation of
$$L(X) = \frac{1}{1+k_1 e^{-k_2(X-k_3)}}$$ where $k_1, k_2, k_3$ are given constants and X is lognormal distributed,i.e., it has the density function
$$f(x; \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{x\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(lnx-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}},  \forall x > 0$$
Now, I obtain
$$\mathbb{E}(L(X)) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}L(x)f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+k_1 e^{-k_2(x-k_3)}} \frac{1}{x\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(lnx-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx.$$
I tried with the change of variable: $z = \frac{lnx - \mu}{\sigma}$ but failed to achieve any closed-form solution.
Can you please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

You need to tell your refrences and your background!
